# Online database of OpenStreetMap data

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, database, online

For now, I have been working on a local PostgreSQL database built on my own machine with OpenStreetMap data that I downloaded and osm2pgsql.

I would like to outsource the computing of my code, namely using Google Colab. I would need access to the database.

I could recreate the database on Google Cloud but this solution would cost me money. I was wondering if there exists an online database, preferably PostgreSQL but any would do, that I could use for free?

Comment: It seems you have multiple questions: 1) How to optimize performance of your query (you believe Google Colab is the solution, but that seems to be an assumption); 2) How to work with OSM data in PostgreSQL in Google Colab without incurring costs?; 3) How to call the Overpass API from Google Colab? The stackexchange format works best if you focus on a single question at a time, show any research you've done so far, and indicate where you could use help. Could you perhaps [edit] your question to focus on one of the three things?

Comment: what size is your database? Supabase has a free (but limited) tier https://supabase.com/pricing

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke : my code is, to my knowledge and the knowledge of my colleague, not optimizable so I'm just gonna turn to multiprocessing to run it faster. I will edit to remove the Overpass reference. Question really is the number 2 in your list: How to work with OSM data in PostgreSQL in Google Colab without incurring costs?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edit. This does seem less related to GIS, but to cloud computing, but I'm not familiar enough with gis.se to know if that's relevant or not. Could you indicate what size of database you are talking about as that narrows down the free options that are available. Also, you indicate that your code is not optimizable, but is the bottleneck in your code or in the database? I.e. does the (free) postgres database need high performance as well?

Comment: Relevant question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030755/connect-to-postresql-database-from-google-colab

Comment: The bottleneck is a native function from postgis that I will not try to optimize as it does a great job. Also, my code is Python and it is full of if-statements, but I have little other choice. As for the SO question: this was my second try, and unfortunately installing postgre on Colab does not do (I would need to pay a fee to run the base on Google's servers) and the local connexion would end up using my machine to compute (defeating the purpose of Colab).

Comment: You seem adamant in hiding how big your database is, so it's hard to know what will or will not work, but I just tried postgres on colab and managed to install and run it without paying anything. Don't know how it performs w.r.t. your local machine. Also, are you aware of the $200-300 of free credit Google Cloud and Azure provide for new users? Perhaps you can use that?